# How to change constructor template in IntelliJ

Tags: java, templates, intellij-idea, lombok

I'm using lombok heavily and got `@RequiredArgsConstructor` in my class templates.

Now lets say I type new Foo("bar"), and class Foo does not exist but I want IntelliJ to create it as well as the constructor.

At the moment IntelliJ creates the following body for the class:

`public Foo(String bar){
}`

But I would like to have this instead:

`@NonNull @Getter String bar;`

Any way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the moment there is no way to customize constructor templates in IntelliJ IDEA.

It may be worth [filing a request to Lombok plug-in developer](https://github.com/mplushnikov/lombok-intellij-plugin/issues) so that he can provide some workaround.

If it turns out that the issue cannot be addressed on the plug-in side, feel free to [submit a request in YouTrack](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA).